# RxJS asynchronous handling of streams

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

```
//app.js
import $ from 'jquery';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

var $pull = $('#fetch');//this is a button id
var pull$ =Rx.Observable.fromEvent($pull,'click').startWith("/hcdata.json");

var $result = $(".datab");//class for HTML table
var classarray = ['id','type','name','image','tn'];

var resp$ = pull$.flatMap(
    function(reqdata){
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(reqdata));
    });

var pri$  = resp$.subscribe(
    function(data){
        var head = Object.keys(data[0]);
        var len = head.length;
        $result.empty();
        $("<tr>").appendTo($result);
        $.each(head,function(i,value){
        $("<th class='tablehead'>"+value.toUpperCase()+"`</th>").appendTo($result)})`
        $("</tr>").appendTo($result);
        console.log(head);

        for( var j= 0;j<data.length;j++)
        {
             $("<tr >").appendTo($result);
            for(var i =0;i<len;i++)
            {
                //alert(data[j][head[i]]);
                $("<td contenteditable='true' class='"+classarray[i]+"''>"+data[j][head[i]]+"</td>").appendTo($result)
            }
            $("</tr>").appendTo($result);
        }

    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    function(){
        console.log("Completed");
    });

    //element assignment
    var $idv = $(".id");
    var $typv = $(".type");
    var $nmv = $(".name");
    var $imgv = $(".image");
    var $tnv = $(".tn");

  //not working with no errors
    var abc$ = Rx.Observable.defer(function(){
        return Rx.Observable.fromEvent($idv,'blur');
    });  

    var lat$ = abc$.map(function(e){
        console.log(e.target.innerText);    
        return e.target.innerText;
    }).flatMap(function(data){
         return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(function(data){
            return Promise.resolve(data);
         });
    });

    var sub = lat$.subscribe(function(x){
        if (x === parseInt(x, 10))
            alert("data is integer")
        else
            alert("data is not an integer")
    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    function(){
        console.log("Finally");
    })
```

I have fetched data from the JSON file mentioned and structuring it into a table, which is working fine.The problem is I want to try to use onblur event on editing any cell and further do validations on the changes made, this event handling is not working with no errors.I am new to this asynchronous style of reactive programming. Please help.

Comment: If there is anything not clear, please let me know

Comment: Your BackTicks are the one causing the problem Check the compiler errors or the brwoser console.

Answer (score 0):

Its again the BackTick Issue. Fix that and then you will be able to understand the actual error.

```
//app.js
import $ from 'jquery';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

var $pull = $('#fetch');//this is a button id
var pull$ =Rx.Observable.fromEvent($pull,'click').startWith("/hcdata.json");

var $result = $(".datab");//class for HTML table
var classarray = ['id','type','name','image','tn'];

var resp$ = pull$.flatMap(
    function(reqdata){
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(reqdata));
    });

var pri$  = resp$.subscribe(
    function(data){
        var head = Object.keys(data[0]);
        var len = head.length;
        $result.empty();
        $("<tr>").appendTo($result);
        $.each(head,function(i,value){
        $("<th class='tablehead'>"+value.toUpperCase()+"`</th>").appendTo($result)})
        $("</tr>").appendTo($result);
        console.log(head);

        for( var j= 0;j<data.length;j++)
        {
             $("<tr >").appendTo($result);
            for(var i =0;i<len;i++)
            {
                //alert(data[j][head[i]]);
                $("<td contenteditable='true' class='"+classarray[i]+"''>"+data[j][head[i]]+"</td>").appendTo($result)
            }
            $("</tr>").appendTo($result);
        }

    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    function(){
        console.log("Completed");
    });

    //element assignment
    var $idv = $(".id");
    var $typv = $(".type");
    var $nmv = $(".name");
    var $imgv = $(".image");
    var $tnv = $(".tn");

  //not working with no errors
    var abc$ = Rx.Observable.defer(function(){
        return Rx.Observable.fromEvent($idv,'blur');
    });  

    var lat$ = abc$.map(function(e){
        console.log(e.target.innerText);    
        return e.target.innerText;
    }).flatMap(function(data){
         return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(function(data){
            return Promise.resolve(data);
         });
    });

    var sub = lat$.subscribe(function(x){
        if (x === parseInt(x, 10))
            alert("data is integer")
        else
            alert("data is not an integer")
    },
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    function(){
        console.log("Finally");
    })
```

Comment: There are no errors in the browser window, if there are there is always a template error thrown